# Como deixar apenas uma borda em JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Gostaria de saber como deixar apenas uma borda em um `JTextField`, parecido com a entrada de dados na hora de logar no Gmail, ou seja, com uma borda apenas no inferior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar bordas com a classe [`MatteBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/border/MatteBorder.html) da seguinte forma:

```
textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.BLUE));
```

O método `createMatteBorder` permite que você defina a espessura de cada borda do componente, além da cor. Basta informar 0 em todos, exceto no terceiro parâmetro, que é equivalente ao tamanho da borda inferior.

Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que para obter o efeito da imagem acima, você precisa aplicar a mesma cor de background da sua tela ao `JTextField`, algo como:

```
textField.setBackground(seuFrame.getBackground());
```

ou

```
textField.setBackground(painelDoTexField.getBackground());
```

senão, apesar de ficar apenas com uma borda visível, o fundo ficará branco, destacando o campo do resto da tela.

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado!

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges disponha :)